# How to do two events in one link <a href..>: to external page (_blank) and to internal page (_self) in event onClick?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link on site: `<a href="https://paypal.com/..." title="Pay now on PayPal"...>Pay now</a>`.
Needs to do next actions:

1. open onClick in new tab external page of PayPal (invoice),
2. open onClick in this tab internal page of next text about confirmation of payment.

Think its about using event(s) onClick in `<a href="#" onClick="...">Pay now</a>`,
but I can`t find working example of this task. Please, help in this question to do working button.

Comment: Is this what you wanted => `<a href="https://paypal.com" title="Pay now on PayPal" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com');">Pay now</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Call this function on your button click:

```
function onClick() { 
   window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank"); 
   window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com";
}
```